# Does IE cache that an image was not found?

Tags: image, internet-explorer, browser-cache

Does Internet Explorer cache a value indicating that an image isn't there (404 Error) if you revisit the site some seconds after the first visit?

In short:

1. First visit of site A with an image that was deleted before
2. First visit of site B
3. Second visit of site A, IE doesn shows any "square with red x" ...

Comment: How are the images being served, direct via web server or via handler etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it does, yes.

However, if you wish to force IE into attempting to reload that image, initiate a "hard-refresh" by pressing Ctrl + F5